# High amount of parameters in Kotlin data class

Tags: kotlin, data-class

I'm making a dictionary-like app with Kotlin in which I have a data class for every word and their meaning + declensions, so I have a data class with about 20 parameters:

```
data class Word(
   val param1: String,
   val param2: String,
   val param3: String,
...
   val param20: String
)
```

Is it ok to have so many parameters or is there a better way to do it?
It's only for storing and then showing the data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure about your specification, but have you considered re-designing your approach where you have a `data class` and have a `list` properties like this?

```
data class Word(
    var name: String,
    var meaning: List<String>,
    var declensions: List<String>
)
```

Though its not bad to have so many parameters inside a class or any construct, you're just limited to `N` parameters (20 in your case).

You can consider having such a `data class` for every word that might have more or less than 20 meanings/declensions, you also don't have to specify an empty argument if the meaning or declensions is less than 20,  but again I'm not sure about your use-case.

Comment: That is a good approach indeed, I haven't thought of it that way. Steryx's answer is also really helpful, though in my case won't be needed since all the results will be shown in a LazyColumn.

Answer (score 2):

z.y's answer is the right solution for your case.

Taking into consideration that you are developing the dictionary app, there might be the case when you will need fast access to exact word's data.
You can store the words in the map, where the keys will be the words themselves, and the values will be the meanings and the declensions. In that case the suggested data class will be excessive.

You can reduce it to

```
data class WordData(
    val meanings: List<String>,
    val declensions: List<String>
)
```

and store it in the map like this

```
val dictionary: HashMap<String, WordData>
```

then you can access, for example, the needed word's meanings like this

```
val word = "dog"
dictionary[word]?.meanings.forEach {
    println(it)
} ?: println("There is no word $word in the dictionary")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could go one step further than the other examples, and build a full data structure if it suits the data you're working with!

Meanings are probably fine in a list, right? But for declensions, you might want to put them in some meaningful structure, instead of just tossing them in a list. You could use *another* data class for that:

```
data class Declensions(
    val nominativeSingular: String? = null,
    val nominativePlural: String? = null,
    val genitiveSingular: String? = null,
    ...
)
```

And that way you're giving meaning to each of the strings you're storing, and you can make use of that meaning when displaying stuff to the user, doing lookups, making test questions, etc!

And you could use that object in your `WordData` class:

```
data class WordData(
    val name: String,
    val meanings: List<String>,
    val declensions: Declensions
)
```

---

An alternative is instead of defining that big `Declensions` object with all possibilities (and leaving them *null* if they're unused), you could define each declension as a piece of data:

```
// an enum like this can let you define a fixed set of possible values
enum class Case { NOMINATIVE, GENITIVE, DATIVE... }

data class Declension(val case: Case, val singular: String, val plural: String)
```

And then add the ones you need:

```
data class WordData(
    val name: String,
    val meanings: List<String>,
    val declensions: List<Declension>
)

val word = WordData(
    name = "wordo",
    meanings = listOf("A made-up word"),
    declensions = listOf(
        Declension(NOMINATIVE, singular = "wordo", plural = "wordoo"),
        ...
    )
)
```

You could also use a *map* instead of a *list*, and map `Case` types to a data object, so there's one object per case (and that object holds all the info for that case's forms).

Really it's an organisational thing, thinking about what represents a specific piece of data you want to represent, and how you can organise that into larger data objects that act as a useful container and organiser. I'm just giving some vague examples - it really depends on the language and the data you need to represent, and what you want to do with it. Maybe the simple lists are fine too! But you definitely have options, and sometimes more structure can be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

1. Is it ok to have so many parameters?

*Certainly not*

2. is there a better way to do it?

*Yes, a few*

One approach would be composite related parameters into a single object

Example firstName, middleName, surName on Person data class

```
data class Name(val firstName: String, val middleName: String, val surName: String)
```

Then encapsulate the original 'Person' class with 'Name' class.

```
data class Person(val name: Name, .....)
```

You have to identify such relations in your 'Word' class.

Another approach would be Builder pattern which is popular in building complex objects. Not sure how feasible that is, in your context.